# Django raw query dynamic query

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have this model:

```
class Stock(models.Model):
    productstockid = models.AutoField(db_column='ProductStockID', primary_key=True)
    productid = models.ForeignKey(Product, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='ProductID')
    quantity = models.IntegerField(db_column='Quantity')
    stocklocationid = models.ForeignKey('StockLocation', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='StockLocationID')

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('productid', 'stocklocationid',)
        managed = False
        db_table = 'stock'
```

And to fill a table (django-tables2) with stocklocation in column I need a query like this.

```
query_text = 'SELECT *'
for s in StockLocation.objects.all():
    query_text += ', SUM(CASE WHEN stocklocationid_id = ' + str(s.stocklocationid) + ' THEN quantity ELSE 0 END) AS ' + s.sl_name
query_text += ' FROM stock GROUP BY productid'
datatest = Stock.objects.raw(query_text)
```

But it is not working. Is Django able to manage it ?

Answer (score 0):

The table names are in the format `appname_modelname`. For example, if your app name is `mystock`, your SQL statement should end with:

```
query_text += ' FROM mystock_stock GROUP BY productid_id'
```

Comment: Actually I saw it in the documentation, but `Stock.objects.raw('SELECT *, productid FROM stock')` works well while `Stock.objects.raw('SELECT *, productid FROM app_stock')` not. And I don't understand why if I remove the '*' from my request it is not working anymore.

Comment: Because if you remove * your column list will start with a comma. You should print the query before executing to see if everything seems ok.

Comment: Be sure I have tested my dynamic querie. It work with a `cursor.execute`<br />I can't understand why `Stock.objects.raw('SELECT *, productid FROM stock')` works and why <br />`Stock.objects.raw('SELECT productstockid, productid FROM stock')` doesn't work